# HTML pre no line wrap border

Tags: html, css, border

I have a `pre` tag with some code in it that doesn't line wrap. I want to put a border around it (`border:1px solid Black;`), but the border is limited to the width of the browser, regardless of the length of the text. How can I force the border to always extend to contain all the text in the `pre` tag?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<pre style="border:2px solid Black;">@Model.Code()</pre>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline` to your `pre` tag CSS.

Comment: That puts a border around every line of text

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark this as answer; I just needed to use `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Ah. I forgot to mention there were multiple lines in the `pre`.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
<pre style="display: inline-block; border:2px solid Black;">
```

Answer (score 5):

For displaying code you want to use

```
pre { white-space:pre-wrap }
```

And for normal text you may want to use

```
pre { white-space:pre-line }
```

`pre-line` makes from multiple white space characters one space character, `pre-wrap` doesn't.

Now if you add a border it will be around the entire text, and the text will be wrapped.

```
pre {
    white-space:pre-line;
    border:2px solid black
}
```

Or didn't you ask for this?